# Recent Chrome version not supporting TLS 1.3 on mac Ventura 13.1

Tags: tls, chrome

Almost latest version of Chrome `112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (x86_64)`, on macOS `Ventura 13.1`, keeps negotiating TLS only up to `1.2` version. I tried some of the same websites in Waterfox (Mozilla based browser) and confirmed `TLS 1.3` via Wireshark.

`chrome://flags` don't seem to have any flag that would affect TLS version.

What could be the reason for this? I am sure that Chrome 112 should support and prefer `TLS 1.3`.

Comment: The current version of Chrome is 113 and it is supporting TLS 1.3 on Ventura 13.1 (just checked). Thus what you are reporting is not reproducible to me. Since you've managed to verify with Wireshark that Waterfox is supporting TLS 1.3 - can you also provide a pcap file which supports your findings of missing TLS 1.3 support in Chrome (screenshot is not enough, since the details of ClientHello and ServerHello are needed).

Comment: What is the best way to share a pcap file here?

Comment: To share a pcap upload it to some file sharing service and provide the link.

Comment: What's the result of https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov "Partial Test Failure, Failed, probably due to firewall restrictions We couldn't detect any secure protocols. Many of our tests run on non-standard protocols; it's possible that you are in an environment that limits outbound connections, thus breaking our tests. If possible, try this test in a different environment." 

While in Waterfox I got "
Your user agent has good protocol support.
Your user agent supports TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3, which are recommended protocol version at the moment."

I am going to start removing all my networking tools now and see if that helps.

Comment: Ha! Deleting Little Snitch Mini solved the issue immediately. Didn't even need to restart Chrome. It is very interesting and also worrying that a free version without any blocking caused TLS 1.3 not to work for certain browsers.

Comment: Resolved as invalid then.

Comment: This is a networking issue, not a security issue, even if TLS version was downgraded.

Answer (score 3):

After Artem provided me with a neat and fast way to test TLS support in browser: https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html
I made a guess that it must be some sort of networking app that is causing inconsistent TLS 1.3 upgrade among my browsers.

Turns out removing [Little Snitch Mini](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch-mini/index.html) fixed the issue.